# Heroku is trying to install sqlite3 gem even it not being in the Gemfile

Tags: sqlite, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bundler

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 3.1 application for the first time on Heroku. I set it to the Cedar stack, removed the sqlite3 gem but when I push the code to Heroku I get this error:

> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc
>          Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --deployment
>          Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/....... (...)
>
> Installing rails (3.1.0)
>          Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to
>   the Bundler issue tracker at
>   https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it.
>   Thanks!
>          /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>          /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>          checking for sqlite3.h... no

I've no idea why bundle install is trying to install sqlite3. Take a look at my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock:

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

gem 'json'
gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
#  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
#  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM   remote: http://rubygems.org/   specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.0)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.0)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.0.3)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
    activemodel (3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.0)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.0)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
    activesupport (3.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    daemons (1.1.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.2.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.14)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.1)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    pg (0.11.0)
    polyglot (0.3.2)
    rack (1.3.3)
    rack-cache (1.0.3)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.0)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.0)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)
      activerecord (= 3.1.0)
      activeresource (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.0)
    railties (3.1.0)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2)
    rdoc (3.9.4)
    sprockets (2.0.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thin (1.2.11)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.29)
    uglifier (1.0.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS   ruby

DEPENDENCIES   jquery-rails   json   pg   rails (= 3.1.0)   thin   uglifier
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: So, the smart guy who voted down could explain why?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, im using 'pg' locally with no problem but Heroku is still trying to install sqlite and therefore erroring. However, i can see that i have the following in my gemfile.lock: `sqlite3 (1.3.4) sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3) sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)`. These are obviously what is causing the problem but i can't work out why they are still making their way into my gemfile.lock; no matter how many times i do `bundle update` or delete the lock file and start from scratch. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have fixed mine by removing the `taps` gem from my Gemfile. Forgot i didn't need it in the actual Gemfile, just within my gemset in order to use it. Removing `taps` removed the sqlite dependancies in my Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Thanks Pete, removing taps (in my case, taps-taps) worked for me :)

Answer (score 34):

When I ran into the problem, turns out I'd forgotten to commit my changes after `bundle install`.  Doh!  `git status` should indicate unstaged changes for the gem files.

Answer (score 3):

I has the same problem and zoltarSpeaks' solution fixed it for me. I had the taps gem installed after reading this article that indicated it would be necessary for pushing from a local sqlite3 to production postgresql: http://batsov.com/articles/2011/10/30/deploying-rails31-apps-on-celadon-cedar/. Turned out I didn't need the taps gem after all, but it was clearly the problem. Removed the reference, bundle update, all systems go.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting Gemfile.lock and run Bundle Install, commit and push

Comment: are you using windows for development?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without uninstalling sqlite3 gem for Heroku:

Add to Gemfile:

```
group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.17.1' #or version of pg you want
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2' #Heroku static assets for image and css
```

Check, that you have:

```
end 
end
```

at the end of code in Gemfile

than Save Gemfile and run bundle install

```
$ bundle install --without production
```

than commit

```
$ git commit -a -m "Update Gemfile.lock for Heroku"
```

than

```
$ git push heroku master
```

That is all. You will get only a few warnings which is simply to fix.