# Rails environment looks like it's stuck to production, even in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

When I run `bundle install` in my Rails application directory, Bundler installs gems that are only in the production group (such as heroku or pg). When I run the rails server locally, it's also trying to look for an activerecord-tcp-adapter that has ZERO results on Google:

```
/Users/atestu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the tcp adapter: `gem install activerecord-tcp-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/tcp_adapter) (LoadError)
```

I suppose this gem is related to heroku's production environment, but my RAILS_ENV variable is empty. And I get the exact same problem when I set it to `development` or when I run `rails s -e development`.

How can I look deeper into this problem?

Edit: here's my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'json'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'rpx_now'
gem 'hominid'
gem 'ruby-tmdb'
gem 'memcached'
gem 'aws-s3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :production do
  gem 'heroku'
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'taps'
end
```

And here is my `database.yml` file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Please also post your database.yml file

Comment: That's weird, are you sure this is your **database.yml** file? It looks a lot like somewhere in your app you're asking rails to connect using a **tcp** adapter.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: Heroku replaces the database.yml file in production with their own config.

Comment: @Kevin it doesn't happen on heroku, happens on his local machine.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares yes I'm sure :) (@Kevin is my coding partner, I'm the front end guy, he does the backend and we just can't figure this one out! We thought it was a problem with Heroku since that's what we use in prod… but no luck so far)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check `.bundle/config` file?

Comment: My .bundle/config in its entirety: 
`---`
`BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production`

I rm'd it but it reappeared after `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Wierd..  Possibly related to the taps gem?  [Removing it from the Gemfile has helped others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378375/805003).

It hasn't been developed in over 11 months and when I included it in my Gemfile, it generated a ruby 1.9.1 folder (and I'm using 1.9.3) with a bunch of gems - could be some conflicts there.  Seems to be the only reference to 'tcp' I can find.  Might be worth using [pgbackups](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#transfers) instead, if possible.

You might also want to consider using the [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/) instead of including it in the Gemfile.

Comment: Just tried removing it (and even uninstalling it completely), still getting the same error…

Answer (score 0):

change database.yml :

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

to

```
 production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

you could check: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3 to get more information

don't forget to upload the code to GIT.